# How do I implement 'beforeSend' function with ajax ASP.NET form TagHelper?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, forms, tag-helpers

I am using the FormTagHelper in ASP.NET Core 2.2 for an ajax form:

```
<form id="myAjaxForm"
      data-ajax="true"
      data-ajax-method="post"
      data-ajax-url="@Url.Action("MyPostAction", "MyController")"
      data-ajax-begin="myBeginFunction"
      data-ajax-success="mySuccessFunction"
      data-ajax-failure="myFailureFunction">
```

[This article](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/ajax/unobtrusive-ajax) lists all the ajax options available for this TagHelper. I can specify callbacks for `begin`, `success`, `failure`, and `complete`, but there is no option to specify `beforeSend`.

**The `beforeSend` function can be specified when using [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ... how do I implement it with FormTagHelper?**

Comment: This isn't a tag helper, it's just HTML with I assume jQuery reading the `data-` attributes.

Comment: The syntax highlighting doesn't show in this code block, but in Visual Studio it highlights `form` in green and says it's a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.FormTagHelper`. But I think you are right that the ajax functionality is coming from `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`, rather than `FormTagHelper`.

Comment: Well yes, `form` is a tag helper, but you're not using any of the features of a tag helper. Why do you want to avoid using the jQuery method though?

Comment: I have a bunch of ajax forms that are already written using the `data-ajax-` attributes and they work well so I would rather not have to move it all to calls to `jQuery.ajax()`

Comment: Don't the two things work together though? Unobtrusive jQuery should still cause the `beforeSend` event to fire right?

Comment: Maybe -- that's part of what I'm asking. And if it does... how do I specify the `beforeSend` function? I already tried `data-ajax-beforeSend="myBeforeSendFunction"`